# Group_by no Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Considere o seguinte data frame:

```
dados <- data.frame(Bairro=c("Bairro1","Bairro2","Bairro3", "Bairro4","Bairro1",
                             "Bairro2","Bairro3", "Bairro4", "Bairro1", "Bairro1"), 
                    Piscina=c("sim","sim","sim","sim","não","não","não","não","não","não"), 
                    Area=c(300,110,400,130,90,160,200,180,210,140))
```

Por enquanto meu códido está retornando o total de casas analisadas e o total de casas com piscinas, agrupando tudo por bairro:

```
library(dplyr)
estatisticas <- dados %>%
  group_by(Bairro) %>%
  summarise(
    Qtd_casas = n(),
    Casas_com_piscina = sum(Piscina=="sim"))
```

Agora gostaria de acrescentar duas novas colunas nesse novo data frame "estatisticas":

- área média das casas com piscina;
- área média das casas sem piscina.

Como consigo isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta acrescentar mais duas linhas ao `summarise` da pergunta.

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  group_by(Bairro) %>%
  summarise(
    Qtd_casas = n(),
    Casas_com_piscina = sum(Piscina == "sim"),
    Area_com_piscina = mean(Area[Piscina == "sim"]),
    Area_sem_piscina = mean(Area[Piscina == "não"])
  ) 
## A tibble: 4 x 5
#  Bairro  Qtd_casas Casas_com_piscina Area_com_piscina Area_sem_piscina
#  <chr>       <int>             <int>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#1 Bairro1         4                 1              300             147.
#2 Bairro2         2                 1              110             160 
#3 Bairro3         2                 1              400             200 
#4 Bairro4         2                 1              130             180
```